# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable during scipy minimize

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, numba

I'm trying to estimate a maximum likelihood model in python. I set up both the likelihood function and the analytic jacobian. When I run scipy minimize, I get a bizarre error (displayed below). This error doesn't seem to occur when I omit the jacobian, but I can't figure out why.

```
from numpy import log,sum,var
from numba import njit

@njit
def log_likelihood(params,surg_fx,surg_fx_ses):
    mu_var = params[0]
    exp_var = mu_var + surg_fx_ses**2
    log_lik = -((surg_fx)**2 / (2*exp_var)) - .5*log(exp_var)
    neg_sum_log_lik = -sum(log_lik)
    print(mu_var)
    print(neg_sum_log_lik)
    if np.isnan(neg_sum_log_lik):
        return 1e20
    else:
        return neg_sum_log_lik

@njit
def log_lik_jac(params,surg_fx,surg_fx_ses):
    mu_var = params[0]
    exp_var = mu_var + surg_fx_ses**2
    jc = -sum(((surg_fx)**2 / (2*(exp_var**2))) - (.5/exp_var))
    print(mu_var)
    print(jc)
    return jc

x0 = [np.var(cost_params3)]
shrinkage_est = minimize(log_likelihood,x0,args=(cost_params3,cost_SEs3),jac=log_lik_jac,options={'disp':True},method='BFGS')
```

`cost_params3` and `cost_SEs3` are (205,)-shaped numpy arrays.

And the return is:

```
0.10423462356390442
-580.1534424527905
0.10423462356390442
-67.02947836460727
[ 1.11423462]
26.84532144252225
[ 1.11423462]
77.95606471086792
[ 0.3741784]
-54.28224588483895
[ 0.3741784]
150.90730570822998
[ 0.19152581]
-79.19268133113846
[ 0.19152581]
68.81484893304786
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 444, in minimize
    return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 973, in _minimize_bfgs
    A1 = I - sk[:, numpy.newaxis] * yk[numpy.newaxis, :] * rhok
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

I'm not really sure why this runs for a few iterations and just fails, especially given that nothing is being subscripted here. I'm also not sure why it seems to become a list after the first iteration? I tried running it without numba but it stopped at the same place with a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 444, in minimize
    return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 973, in _minimize_bfgs
    A1 = I - sk[:, numpy.newaxis] * yk[numpy.newaxis, :] * rhok
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your `log_lik_jac` appears to be returning a scalar. As explained in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize), the `jac` function is supposed to return a gradient vector. Why are you returning a scalar?

Comment: Since you didn't label the outputs, I'm not sure which line comes from which `print`.  However, since they come in pairs, it appears that you are returning a scalar float where the internal routines require an indexed sequence (e.g. list).  If you *think* you're sending a list, try printing the type of `jc` as well, to check your assumption.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem, but there's an outstanding installation bug for `numba` on some OS's.

Comment: Thanks, @user2357112 and @Prune! I didn't think about the fact that it wants to receive an array and not a scalar. I replaced `return jc` with `return np.array([jc])` and that solved the issue. (Not sure how to mark this question as answered)